# Page Caching / Back Button Issue

Tags: bug, caching

For the past week or so it seems that there is an issue on stackoverflow that brings back very old (days) copies of the page.

For example:

When I go to the Tags button, then select the C# tag and view the newest questions, I select a question and then hit the Back button (usually the Backspace key on my keyboard), and it brings back a cached page that is days old.

This seems new in the past week or so. I know there are navigation changes going on so I'm not sure if its related. I'm using the latest Chrome, and I'm having the same issue on my desktop, laptop, and tablet. Its mildly annoying to have to refresh the page after hitting the back button, I swear this wasn't an issue 2-3 weeks ago.