# Bug - going back a page displays cached content from a week ago

Tags: bug, caching

Ok, I know there was a similar question about a year ago [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/300764/page-caching-back-button-issue) and [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/300233/new-homepage-navigation-breaks-back-button/) regarding the main page, however I can't seem to find anything about other pages, so my guess is that's a different issue (especially that the aforementioned questions are marked as completed).

I'm getting a cached version of the activity page (from 25th of August or so), after performing the following steps:

1. On my activity page, I click on "X posts editted" link
2. Go to suggestions
3. Click any "approved/rejected/pending edit" link
4. Press back in the browser.

Goes away when the page is reloaded.

I've got screenshots documenting it, and I can repeat it every single time I take these steps.

Comment: Are you sure this is an issue with the site and not just something your browser does with most any site?

Comment: I haven't noticed any issues on other websites at all. Could you tell me how to test it thoroughly please? Happens in Chrome but NOT in Edge (will test Firefox when I get home).

Comment: Perhaps try in incognito mode. It might be an extension that you have in Chrome that causes it. I can't reproduce on latest Chrome, Windows 7.

Comment: I don't have any extensions other than Google Docs/Sheets/Slides. Latest Chrome, Windows 10. Incognito unsurprisingly solved it, so did clearing cache. I just found it a little ridiculous that it had a cached copy from a week ago.

Comment: Probably an odd setting in your Chrome, then. I'd go through and look at your settings, see if anything looks odd.

Comment: Nothing really stands out. At this point I'm willing to ignore it, since I doubt it will get anywhere. Thank you both, @Kendra and BoltClock for your time. Will let you know if it gets more persistent. And hopefully if anyone has this problem, they'll mention it as well.

Comment: A lot of people recently have been reporting browser caches as "bugs" with Stack Overflow. I'm not really sure why this is happening. As far as I know, nothing has changed on the browser front; they have *always* aggressively cached pages when you use the forward/back buttons. And I don't really understand how developers who use Stack Overflow don't already know this. In your specific case, you might be surprised to see week-old caches, but that's not even a bug, it's just a little bit surprising. Check [here](http://shouldiblamecaching.com/) for an answer to similar problems.